# Please explain the example in Tcl's Rule 5

Tags: syntax, tcl

The documentation (https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) says:

> For instance, `“cmd a {*}{b [c]} d {*}{$e f {g h}}”` is equivalent to `“cmd a b {[c]} d {$e} f {g h}”`.

But why is `$e` in braces after substitution? Where are those coming from (and why aren't the other arguments in the word (`f` and `{g h}`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$e` is in braces to stop it from being evaluated. `f` and `{g h}` aren't variables or in square brackets like `c` is, so don't need them.

These examples will also all expand to the same thing:

```
cmd a {*}[list b {[c]}] d {*}[list {$e} f {g h}]
cmd a {*}[list b {[c]}] d {*}[list \$e f {g h}]
cmd a {*}{b [c]} d {*}"\$e f {g h}"
```